# Uploading Room Database objects to Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

In my application I have to upload a selective `Notes` object to Firestore database. I want the id to be unique so I have a function to change the id, which is the primary key (I read that this is not good practice but for the time being, this works). I want to change the `id` of my `Notes` object to the firestore document id.

After successfully uploading the document to firestore, I want to change the primary key and set the value of `uploaded` to 1 using `changeId` and `upload` functions.

```
@Dao
interface NoteDao {

    @Query("UPDATE notes SET id = :newId WHERE id = :Id")
    suspend fun changeId(Id:String, newId:String)

    @Query("UPDATE notes SET uploaded = 0 WHERE id = :Id")
    suspend  fun upload(Id:String)
}
```

I'm calling these functions from a fragment like

```
fun uploadNote(){
        val collectionRef = firestore.collection(userId)
        val docRef = collectionRef.document()
        var note = Notes()
        launch {
            context?.let {
                note = NotesDatabase.getDatabase(it).noteDao().getSpecificNote(noteId)
                if (note.uploaded == 0) {
                    //If note is not already uploaded, add it as a new document
                    NotesDatabase.getDatabase(it).noteDao().upload(noteId) 
                             //changing value of uploaded as 1
                    NotesDatabase.getDatabase(it).noteDao().changeId(noteId, docRef.id) 
                            //changing noteId as primary key of the firestore document 
                    note.id = docRef.id
                    note.uploaded = 1

                    docRef.set(note)
                        .addOnSuccessListener{
                            Toast.makeText((requireActivity()), "Note Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
                        }.addOnFailureListener {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                requireActivity(),
                                "Error while Uploading Note",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            )
                                .show()
                        }
                } else {
                    //If the note is already uploaded, update it
                    
                    title.text = resources.getString(R.string.uploading_note)

                    firestore.collection(userId).document(note.id).update(
                        note.id,
                        mapOf(
                            "color" to note.color,
                            "dateTime" to note.dateTime,
                            "imgPath" to note.imgPath,
                            "lock" to note.lock,
                            "noteText" to note.noteText,
                            "subTitle" to note.subTitle,
                            "title" to note.title,
                            "webLink" to note.webLink,
                        )
                    )

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to implement this. This is my first project with Room and Firestore and I can't find out why this is not working. Can you please help me figure out the problem?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: When I call these functions, I want to update the noteId and uploaded fields. I can change the noteId, but uploaded is not getting updated


 NotesDatabase.getDatabase(it).noteDao().upload(noteId) 
                             //changing value of uploaded as 1